# Lifetimes of thread::scope()'s variables and spawned threads

Tags: multithreading, rust, lifetime

I'm trying to do some parallel processing on a list of values:

```rust
fn process_list(list: Vec<f32>) -> Vec<f32> { // Block F
    let chunk_size = 100;
    let output_list = vec![0.0f32;list.len()];

    thread::scope(|s| { // Block S
        (0..list.len()).collect::<Vec<_>>().chunks(chunk_size).for_each(|chunk| { // Block T
            s.spawn(|| {
                chunk.into_iter().for_each(|&idx| {
                    let value = calc_value(list[idx]);
                    unsafe {
                        let out = (output_list.as_ptr() as *mut f32).offset(idx as isize);
                        *out = value;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
    output_list
}
```

The API says that `thread::scope()` only returns once each thread spawned by the scope it creates has finished. However, the compiler is telling me that the temporary range object `(0..list.len())` is deconstructed while the threads that use it might still be alive.

I'm curious about what's actually happening under the hood. My intuition tells me that each thread spawned and variable created within Block S would both have Block S's lifetime. But clearly the threads have a lifetime longer than Block S.

Why aren't these lifetimes be the same?

Is the best practice here to create a variable in Block F that serves the purpose of the temporary like so:

```rust
fn process_list(list: Vec<f32>) -> Vec<f32> { // Block F
    let chunk_size = 100;
    let output_list = vec![0.0f32;list.len()];
    let range = (0..list.len()).collect::<Vec<_>>();

    thread::scope(|s| { // Block S
        range.chunks(chunk_size).for_each(|chunk| { // Block T
            s.spawn(|| {
                chunk.into_iter().for_each(|&idx| {
                    let value = calc_value(list[idx]);
                    unsafe {
                        let out = (output_list.as_ptr() as *mut f32).offset(idx as isize);
                        *out = value;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
    output_list
}
```

Comment: In the version which the compiler rejects, on precisely which line do you believe your temporary range variable is dropped? If you look carefully you'll spot that it's one line above the end of the scope block!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to ask SO to find out what happens under the hood of `std` functions, their source code is [readily available](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/thread/scoped.rs.html#129-161), but since you asked I'll try to explain a little more in the comments.

> ```rust
> pub fn scope<'env, F, T>(f: F) -> T
> where
>     F: for<'scope> FnOnce(&'scope Scope<'scope, 'env>) -> T,
> {
>     // `Scope` creation not very relevant to the issue at hand
>     let scope = ...;
>
>     // here your 'Block S' gets run and returns.
>     let result = catch_unwind(AssertUnwindSafe(|| f(&scope)));
>     // the above is just a fancy way of calling `f` while catching any panics.
>
>     // but we're waiting for threads to finish running until here
>     while scope.data.num_running_threads.load(Ordering::Acquire) != 0 {
>         park();
>     }
>     // further not so relevant cleanup code
>     //...
> }
> ```

So as you can see your assumption that 'Block S' will stick around as long as any of the threads is wrong.

---

And yes the solution is to capture the owner of the chunks before you call `thread::scope`.
There is also no reason to dive into `unsafe` for your example, you can use `zip` instead:

```rust
fn process_list(list: Vec<f32>) -> Vec<f32> { // Block F
    let chunk_size = 100;
    let mut output_list = vec![0.0f32; list.len()];
    let mut zipped = list
        .into_iter()
        .zip(output_list.iter_mut())
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    thread::scope(|s| { // Block S
        zipped.chunks_mut(chunk_size).for_each(|chunk| { // Block T
            s.spawn(|| {
                chunk.into_iter().for_each(|(v, out)| {
                    let value = calc_value(*v);
                    **out = value;
                });
            });
        });
    });
    output_list
}
```